# Installing and importing Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, installation, google-earth-engine-python-api, anaconda

Until this morning, I was able to use Google Earth Engine via the Python API in anaconda through ArcGIS. However, I updated ArcGIS and am having to reinstall everything.

I installed gee using `conda install -c conda-forge earthengine-api`

However, when I try to authenticate Google Earth Engine via `earthengine authenticate`, as I did before, I get the following error message:

```
Fetching credentials using gcloud
'gcloud' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
gcloud failed. Please check for any errors above and install gcloud if needed.
```

I installed gcloud from here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install

However, when I try to install gee using conda, it seems to install, but then when I go into Python and type `import ee`, I get an error message that it isn't installed.

Seemed pretty simple before, and not sure how this is set up now. I formerly used Python, generated TIFFs, and downloaded to Google Drive. What is the process now?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that ArcGIS Pro does not handle `activate <environment name>` in conda the way that it normally operates. I used `proswap <environment name>` and this corrected the problem, as it allows for the use of the corrected python environment. See the solution at [Python Command Prompt not changing environments correctly](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/python-command-prompt-not-changing-environments/td-p/1118430)